# Unable to import TA-lib with Macbook Pro M1 chip macOS Big Sur version 11.4

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, ta-lib

I have successfully installed `TA-Lib` using the following commands:

```
brew install ta-lib
pip3 install ta-lib
```

After that, command `pip3 list` have shown `TA-Lib` version.

```
TA-Lib             0.4.21
```

However, when I tried to `import talib`, an error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/talib/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from ._ta_lib import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _TA_ACOS
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

Could you please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to set environment variables mentioned at https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/  ?

Comment: Yep I have tried this just now.

Comment: If you are using a M1 laptop and Homebrew, then you can set these before installing:

export TA_INCLUDE_PATH="$(brew --prefix ta-lib)/include"
export TA_LIBRARY_PATH="$(brew --prefix ta-lib)/lib"

Comment: But I still could not import talib.

Comment: what was the output while execution of `brew install ta-lib` ? remove it and install again to get logs

Comment: ==> Downloading https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/homebrew-bottles/bottles/ta-lib-0.4.0.arm64_big_sur.bottle.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/jiawei/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b4fb52cfa5bf4d7b9f7b0d5908600dd9d44f23e90710c4575c3b91c42e7e957d--ta-lib-0.4.0.arm64_big_sur.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Pouring ta-lib-0.4.0.arm64_big_sur.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/ta-lib/0.4.0: 15 files, 2.3MB

Comment: Ok, and what is `pip3 install ta-lib` output? You may use https://pastebin.com/ if it's too long.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it。
system is MacOS M1 | python 3.9
I try `brew install` and `pip install` is not work, talib can't import.

---

### So, my solution is try to use [anaconda]

1. choose download anaconda MacOS M1:  https://www.anaconda.com/download
2. install the app [anaconda] and create Environments
3. use [PyCharm],
4. [Chose Add Python Interperter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5yQg.png)
5. [Choose Conda Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Q5w.png)
6. Enable [ok] btn
7. Coding...and [Finish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb89J.png)