# DLOpen Error with OpenBB & TALib packages on Mac M1

Tags: jupyter, ta-lib

I'm trying to run OpenBB SDK on my M1 MacBook through Jupyter Notebooks, but I'm running into issues whenever OpenBB references TA-Lib. I've tried many solutions posted online with other TA-Lib issues, but I'm having trouble resolving what's going on. Wanted to come here for help if anyone has suggestions.

```
from openbb_terminal.sdk import openbb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc("font", size=12)
import datetime
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd

es = openbb.stocks.load("ES=F")

openbb.ta.ma_chart(
    data = es['Adj Close'],
    symbol = 'E-Mini S&P Futures',
    #ma_type = 'SMA',
    window = [21, 150])
```

I get this error:

```
Error: dlopen(/Users/brandonbest/anaconda3/envs/obb/lib/python3.10/site-packages/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_TA_ACOS'
```

Info:
Python 3.10.9
TA-Lib 0.4.28

I solutions in the related posts:
[Symbol Not Found in Flat Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006614/what-does-symbol-not-found-expected-in-flat-namespace-actually-mean)
[M1 TA-Lib Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69362274/unable-to-import-ta-lib-with-macbook-pro-m1-chip-macos-big-sur-version-11-4)
[TA-Lib Installation](https://github.com/TA-Lib/ta-lib-python#installation)